# How can I create a method that retrieves the list of spreadsheets in excel file and return back the sheets as a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a class, where one of the methods `"load()"` wants to receive an excel file, retrieve the list of spreadsheets in the excel file and then return back the individual sheets of the file as a dictionary:

For example:

```
{“Sheet Name 1”: DataFrame,
“Sheet Name 2”: DataFrame,
“Sheet Name N”: DataFrame}
```

I am unsure of how best to do this. Other forums have suggested me to use `xlrd` or `openpyxl` but I have tried and can't solve this currently.

Comment: Can you share the input and expected output samples. In your example, is this an input. what is DataFrame? a string or the actual DataFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use openpyxl as follows

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook(filename="testing.xlsx")

# create the dictionary to hold the dataframes
data_dict = {}

# loop through each sheet, storing the sheetname and the dataframe
for sheet in workbook.sheetnames:
    data_dict[sheet] = pd.read_excel('testing.xlsx', sheet_name=sheet)
```